# Excel Solver using Macro

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I have a excel file with 300 rows of data and i need to use a solver in each row. There's an equation in each cell of column K that should equal zero by changing cell H9.

Solver:

- Target cell : K9 (should equal "0")
- By changing  cell : H9
- Output cell: H9

The solver should work from row 9 to row 309.

I can find a lot of similar problems on the internet but I'm not able to modify the programming code to my case.

```
*Sub Macro2()
' Macro2 Macro
'
Sneltoets: Ctrl+v
'
Dim c As Range
Dim nRows As Integral
nRows = 300
For Each c In Range("$H$9:$H$309")
        SolverOk SetCell:=c.Offset(0, 3), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=c.Address, _
            Engine:=1, EngineDesc:=" GRG Nonlinear "
        SolverSolve userfinish:=True
        SolverFinish keepfinal:=1
Next
End Sub*
```

Its the first time I have to program something in Excel.

If someone could help me, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far, even it it's not working? Also what does "K9 to value 0" mean?

Comment: I have edited the topic.

Comment: @Jelle - please post the code you found helpful as an answer and mark it as such so those coming after can see the answer more clearly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the script below and it worked fine for me.  You may need to add a small tweak or two, to get it to do exactly what you want, but based on my understanding of what you want, it should be very close to what you need.

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim c As Range
Dim nRows As Integer
Dim i As Integer
nRows = 300

i = 9
For Each c In Range("$H$9:$H$309")

    c.Select
    SolverOk SetCell:=Range("H" & i), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range("K" & i), Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve True
    i = i + 1

Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I used this code a couple of times and it worked in most cases.

I now have an additional question.

Is it possible to add a code to make sure that all solution in the cells of column K are always bigger than the solution in the previous cell of collumn K (ex: K9 > K8,...., K309 > K308 )?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code and it worked:

```
Sub example()

Dim oRng    As Range
Dim c       As Range

Set oRng = Range("K9:K309")
For Each c In oRng
    c.GoalSeek _
      Goal:=0, _
      ChangingCell:=c.Offset(0, -3)
Next c

End Sub
```

The code written by queens_living even did a better job.

Thanks!